# Is there an sp_reset or the equivalent?

Tags: sql-server, linux, default-value

Let's say I was monkeying around on SQL Server and I wanted to reset everything to factory defaults, is that currently possible?

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
EXEC sp_configure 'stupid dangerous thingz', 1
```

I want to do something like

```
EXEC sp_factory_reset, 1
```

Comment: AFAIK there isn't anything to reset to defaults. Your best option, currently, is to take the output of sys.configurations on a new install and create a cheat sheet. Obviously this can be made into your own reset stored procedure. Note that some options are also controlled through alter server configuration. In general, though, there shouldn't be a need to change *most* options as their default is 0 which is to change dynamically.

Comment: sp_blitz will tell you if you have non-default configurations and what the default value is in the details. https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/

Comment: Microsoft documentation contains a complete list of config options and their default values https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-configuration-options-sql-server You could also use the Export/Import funcationality of the opensource DBATools.io project to set and reset them https://dbatools.io/functions/export-dbaspconfigure/

Comment: @BobKlimes seriously that's the best suggestion I've seen. If you want to answer with that, I'll mark it as chosen. That's the best tool for the job I see being offered here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[sp_blitz](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/) will show you all non-default configuration settings and the details show what the default is.

[image]

Another option would be to use [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/) to export the config on a fresh install, using export-dbaspconfigure. Then import when you want to reset, using import-dbaspconfigure.

```
Export-DbaSpConfigure -ServerInstance . -path c:\temp\sp_configure.sql
```

This will create a file with all sp_configure options in this format

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options' , 1;  RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
EXEC sp_configure 'recovery interval (min)' , 0;
EXEC sp_configure 'allow updates' , 0;
EXEC sp_configure 'user connections' , 0;
EXEC sp_configure 'locks' , 0;
EXEC sp_configure 'open objects' , 0;
EXEC sp_configure 'fill factor (%)' , 0;
EXEC sp_configure 'disallow results from triggers' , 0;
```

Then you can either run this file or the import-spdbaconfigure command, which will run the script for you

```
import-DbaSpConfigure -ServerInstance . -path c:\temp\sp_configure.sql
```

Comment: I wanted to actually download, install, and run this before I marked this as chosen. I do like this `sp_blitz` tool though.

Answer (score 1):

eg this will emit a script based on the configuration of an instance that can be applied on another instance.

```
select 'exec sp_configure ''show advanced options'', 1;'
union all
select concat('exec sp_configure ',' ''', name, ''', ', cast(value as varchar(200) ), ';' )
from sys.configurations
union all 
select 'exec sp_configure ''show advanced options'', 0;'
union all
select 'reconfigure;'
```

Comment: My problem is I changed all kinds of crap. It's how I run. Now I want to know if I broke it or if it was born this way. ;)